# Do i have to pay customs on a year old desktop computer while travelling to india from usa

Tags: indian-citizens

I built a gaming pc in usa and want to take it back to india will i be charged in customs? If yes how much?(the cost of the pc is around 2000 to 2200 usd) also if i bring a monitor (24 inch) how much will be the customs?

Comment: You intend to leave it in India? Eg not take it with you next time you leave?

Comment: No i am coming back to india after my studies dont wana go back

Answer (score 1):

India, along with most other countries, allows you to bring your personal effects into the country duty free when you move there, as long as they are for your personal use. While there may be exceptions for very expensive items, a $2500 PC will not be a problem.

Comment: References please.